# Execute commands directly in DSM?

Tags: nas, synology, dms

I just bought a synology nas ds720+ and I'm trying to setup it as a media server.

But first I want to know, is there a way to execute commands directly in DMS ? like commands to create folders, open files etc etc

I know that I can do things from ssh but I want to setup my nas when I'm in pause at work when I have nothing to do. From here I can't launch ssh or cmd, I can only access to my nas from dsm.

Anyway, sorry for not using the good terms and having a bad english.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Browser at work, this could help you, but you would need to install a plugin.

https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/133977